# Why do I see a frequency shift of the peak between the S11 and impedance response?

Tags: frequency-spectrum

I have a resonator I am trying to characterize, and the S11-Plot gives me a slightly different center (resonant) frequency than that of the Z-Plot.

These measurements were taken simultaneously and using the same VNA. Yet the Z (magnitude and phase) are shifted to the left by something like 5% (Way more than VNA resolution).

Is there a physical reason, or a calibration error reason, or any other for this?

Comment: Can you include a Smith Chart measurement and also what S11 is when you bypass the resonator (should be > -40 dB if properly calibrated).

Comment: Also compare what you get when you terminate the output of your resonator with the same load used for cal and measure S11 of the resonator, did that change the location of your S11 null?

Comment: @DanBoschen Thank you for your reply. I did not record the Smith Chart (Silly me), but I can confirm that a shorted measurement yields more than -40dB. 
I will try to terminate with a 50 ohm and see.
On the other hand, I know that S11= (Z-Zo)/(Z+Zo) and these are all complex. Wouldn't that create an apparent frequency shift? Could that be the reason?
If so which (S11 or Z) represents my true resonance?

Comment: See my answer where I came up with a case where this can occur and not be due to calibration. The actual Smith Chart showing the trajectory vs frequency will be very insightful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[This is more of an electronics related question and perhaps should be migrated to Electronics.SE?]*

This can occur with a series parasitic inductance or capacitance in the resonator; the case with a series inductance is demonstrated below.

The Smith Chart visual provides immediate insight of a shunt L-C resonator (tank circuit) to ground. In the first plot where we have no parasitic inductance in series with an exaggerated parasitic resistance in the resonator (reducing the input impedance at resonance when the reactive inductance cancels the reactive capacitance). At resonance $X_{Lp}$ cancels $X_{Cp}$ and we would be at the large dot shown (with just the shunt resistance due to finite Q remaining, in parallel with the 50 ohm load and thus reducing the input impedance along the resistance axis). As we move off resonance lower in frequency the tank circuit is inductive and ultimately a short to ground at DC, following the shunt inductance trajectory as shown by the path marked $L_p$ indicating a parallel inductor to ground, as we sweep the test frequency toward DC terminating on the left origin in the Smith Chart consistent with a short circuit. As we go higher in frequency the tank circuit will be capacitive and ultimately a short to ground at $f=\infty$, following the shunt capacitor trajectory as shown by the path marked $C_p$ as we sweep the frequency higher.   In this case for all other frequencies other than at resonance the net impedance of the tank would smaller with a maximum tank impedance at resonance, and the resonance peak would match the S11 null.

[image: Smith Chart]

Observe if the tank circuit had a series inductance effectively prior to the shunt L and C to ground. This inductor in series would follow the trajectory marked by $L_s$ (and would ultimately end at the right origin where $Z=\infty$, terminating at the large dot shown at resonance with $X_{Lp} = -X_{Cp}$. As we move off resonance upward in frequency, the resonator adds a shunt capacitance that in this case brings us closer to the center origin (where Z=50 ohms, perfect match), providing a lower S11 as it maximizes the net impedance of the resonator's connection to ground; essentially the resonator is tuning out the series inductance as it becomes capacitive. Not detailed here is that series inductance would also increase as frequency increases but we can see how if the capacitance relative to the inductance is significantly larger that the trajectory would move down faster than up and to the right resulting in the minimum as the OP is seeing. Further the inductance itself would have a point where it resonates out and becomes capacitive, so we could also easily envision the possible case of a net circular path of the series inductance and shunt capacitance of the resonator passing right through the center of the Smith chart (or closer to it).

[image: Smith Chart 2]

Below is a basic simulation of this compliments of https://www.will-kelsey.com/smith_chart/

At resonance the Smith chart would be at DP5 (where the red line intersects the black line to the upper left of center. As we sweep frequency, the trajectory follows the red line where we see a minimum impedance is reached which is not on the resonance of the shunt L and C.

[image: Simulation]

Comment: In my case, since maximum Z is observed at a lower frequency than the S11 minimum, it would seem to be a parasitic parallel capacitance (Which actually makes physical sense in my case). Correct?
Also, thanks for the fantastic answer!

Comment: @Aladdin Effectively, yes! Very perceptive of you. Would be interesting to see your actual Smith Chart. Also depending on your operating frequency transmission line effects could also be at play but this is the lumped element equivalent explanation.

Comment: @Aladdin To be clear not a parallel capacitance as that would just increase C shunt and would reduce your resonant frequency, but a series capacitance instead of series inductance as I drew.